# Grainy images in Firefox but not Chrome

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox

We are using a png image as our logo on our main site. The image is about 85x57 pixels. Whenever we are viewing the website on Chrome, the image looks smooth. However, on firefox the image is grainy and one can distinguish each pixel. Is this a common browser issue with Chrome? Or is there a quick fix for this?

Comment: Could be related to a scalability bug that is mentioned in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918595/why-is-firefox-so-bad-at-resizing-images).

Comment: A link with the image would be helpful

Comment: I'm going to assume the firefox bug is the issue. To solve it, I'll just create a mini logo and render it as it's native size on the site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "grainy-look" could be the result of a bug in Firefox as mentioned in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918595/why-is-firefox-so-bad-at-resizing-images).

Answer (score 1):

Browsers have different methods of interpolating images when NOT rendered at their native size.

Best advice: render the image at its native size.