# Html pixelated edge on image with transparent background

Tags: html, css, image, web, pixel

I have an image of the skype logo that has a transparent background, you can see them here http://test.24car.ro/index.php , on the left, in the blue section that allows you to contact people though skype. Those pictures look fine in chrome but in firefox and opera their edges look pixelated. Why is that? Is it because of how the browser resizes them? What can i do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at a past question: 
[Why is Firefox so bad at resizing images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918595/why-is-firefox-so-bad-at-resizing-images/14308227#14308227)

Basically the solution is to give *transform: rotate( .0001deg );* to the elements

```
<img class="skype_icon" src="..." />
```

CSS

```
.skype_icon {
    transform: rotate( 0.0001deg);
    height: 26px;
    width: 26px;
}
```