# Oversized image is blurry when reduced

Tags: html, css, image

this is my first attempt at a responsive design so excuse me if this is a stupid simple question.

I have created an image and set its max-width to no larger than the actually width of the image since I know that scaling up an image will result in blurry nastiness.

What I am a bit confused on is that as I contract the window and the img begins to shrink, it gets blurry as well...

Is this correct behavior and is there some way around this?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: where is your code ??? I think it needs improvement

Comment: When you are contracting the window does the image shrink as well? I'm guessing you have the image width set as a % and then added a max width?

Comment: yes it does shrink, i have the wrapping div set to a percentage and the img tag set to width: 100%; height: auto; max-width: 480px;

Comment: Not sure what changed but it seems as though the images display correctly now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your using Fire Fox it has been reported to have problems scaling down images.

[Why is Firefox so bad at resizing images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5918595/why-is-firefox-so-bad-at-resizing-images)

[Firefox blurs an image when scaled through external CSS or inline style.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388492/firefox-blurs-an-image-when-scaled-through-css-or-inline-style)

Apparently adding the following to the CSS has fixed the problem for some

```
image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
```

Comment: I am using Firefox and actually it seems as though when I view in Safari it displays correctly. It does seem to be firefox specific however adding the rule above did sharpen the images, but too much making it worse actually.

Comment: I think for the time being its acceptable but I will need to figure out a better way to display images in a flexible layout like this. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Nice, though the problem is also in webkit, at least Chrome

Comment: In case anyone else comes here: "image-rendering: optimizequality" helped me without going nearly as sharp as "-moz-crisp-edges" did.

Comment: In case anyone else comes here again: Chrome only supports `pixelated` though it recognizes `optimizeQuality` and `optimizeSpeed` however it does nothing (at least not when using `background-resize`).