# Firefox blurs scaled images

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, scale

On my site, I have icons sized using percentages.

They show up beautifully on Chrome and even in IE

[image]

But in Firefox, they blur like so

[image]

```
<style>
  #exampleicon 
  { 
  background-image: url(assets/resume.ico);
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-clip: border-box;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 0.2s;
  width: 15%;
  height: auto;
  }
</style>
```

I tried using the `-moz-crisp-edges` method described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388492/firefox-blurs-an-image-when-scaled-through-css-or-inline-style) but the images simply pixelate.

Comment: can you recreate this in a fiddle? It's hard to test without your html and image

Comment: Sorry about that. Since you can't use local storage on Fiddle I used imgur and [it works now on the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R7F9E/) I guess Firefox just had a problem with the ico files? I was using png but the edges weren't smooth on resizing and I couldn't find a decent svg converter that retained transparency/colour.